# How to update list item in sql?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqliteopenhelper

This is my list  activity:

```
 public class List extends ActionBarActivity{

private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
private PersonDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private ListView listView;

private static final String TAG = List.class.getSimpleName();

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    databaseHelper = new PersonDatabaseHelper(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);



                Intent intent = new Intent(List.this, Edit.class);
                Person p = new Person();
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) customAdapter.getItem(position);
                p.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_name"));
                p.surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_surname"));
                p.enterDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_enterdate"));
                p.enterTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_entertime"));
                p.exitDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exitdate"));
                p.exitTime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person_exittime"));


                intent.putExtra("id", position);                               
                intent.putExtra("name",p.name);
                intent.putExtra("surname",p.surname );
                intent.putExtra("enterdate",p.enterDate );
                intent.putExtra("entertime",p.enterTime);
                intent.putExtra("exitdate", p.exitDate);
                intent.putExtra("exittime", p.exitTime);

                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    }); 
    // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
    // so its safe to call database query in another thread
    // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(List.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });
}

    public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

      startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Permission.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

}

    public void onClickLogOut(View btnLogOut){
   Intent intent = new Intent(List.this,
           MainActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_name"), data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_surname"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_enterdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_entertime"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exitdate"),data.getExtras().getString("tag_person_exittime"));

        customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
    }
}
```

This is my Edit activity then i press on list view item :

```
   public class Edit extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText name;
EditText surName;
EditText date;
EditText time;
EditText eDate;
EditText eTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
     String data_name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
     String data_surname = intent.getStringExtra("surname");
     String data_enterdate= intent.getStringExtra("enterdate");
     String data_entertime = intent.getStringExtra("entertime");
     String data_exitdate = intent.getStringExtra("exitdate");
     String data_exittime = intent.getStringExtra("exittime"); //typo here


     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); //corrected
     surName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usersurname); //corrected
     date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date2);
     time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
     eDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date3);
     eTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time3);

     name.setText(data_name);
     surName.setText(data_surname);
     date.setText(data_enterdate);
     time.setText(data_entertime);
     eDate.setText(data_exitdate);
     eTime.setText(data_exittime);
}

public void onCancel(View btnCancel){
finish();
 }
 public void onClickSave(View btnSave){

        }
 }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
  }
```

So in this Edit activity is defined button public onClickSave(View btnSave), i want to make a database upgrade after i press this button, after a lot of tries, i managed to upgrade database but it wont update clciked item in the list, it just creates a new (one more item) in the list. So i am starting from the beginning again :( .

This is my DatabaseHelper:

```
 public class PersonDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String TAG =    PersonDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

// database configuration
// if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

// table configuration
 static final String TABLE_NAME = "person_table";         // Table name
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME = "person_name";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME = "person_surname";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE = "person_enterdate";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME = "person_entertime";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE = "person_exitdate";
 static final String PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME = "person_exittime";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

// this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with PersonDatabaseHelper,
// but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
public PersonDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

    openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

     public void insertData (String aPersonName, String aPersonSurName,   String aPersonEnterDate,String aPersonEnterTime, String aPersonExitDate,String aPersonExitTime) {

    // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME, aPersonName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME, aPersonSurName);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE, aPersonEnterDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME, aPersonEnterTime);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE, aPersonExitDate);
    contentValues.put(PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME, aPersonExitTime);

    database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    }

    public Cursor getAllData () {

    String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

    return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
}


  // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database    related operation 

private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
        super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

     @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Create your tables here

        String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_SURNAME + " TEXT, " + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_ENTERTIME + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITDATE + " TEXT," + PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_EXITTIME + " TEXT )";

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Database schema upgrade code goes here

        String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the  beginning
    }
  }
 }
```

This is my custom cursor:

```
 public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item, parent, false);

    return retView;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView textViewPersonsurName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.surName);
    textViewPersonsurName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    textViewPersonEnterDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));

    TextView textViewPersonEnterTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    textViewPersonEnterTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date2);
    textViewPersonExitDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(5))));

    TextView textViewPersonExitTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2);
    textViewPersonExitTime.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(6))));
}

  }
```

And person class :

```
  public class Person {
String name;
String surname;
String enterDate;
String enterTime;
String exitDate;
String exitTime;
  }
```

This is my list

[image]

This is Edit activity then i press on item :

[image]

So and there u can see my add button which updates info.

Comment: I can only see **INSERT** code... where is your **UPDATE** code? And, possibly, also your **DELETE** code?

Comment: so i donkt know how to update exact item in the list

Comment: So you need to follow a SQLite **CRUD** tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). In particular, take a look at section 9, where you can find info about ContentProviders, Loaders and CursorAdapter. The example shows how to use a SimpleCursorAdapter, you can slightly modify it to use a CursorAdapter; in any case, if you follow that tutorial you have a very clean code and a database that notifies automatically your UI when a INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE is performed against the database.

Comment: If you don't like it, you can use [sqlbrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite). It's a library that can help you.